# Passing arguments forward to another javascript function

Tags: javascript

I've tried the following with no success:

```
function a(args){
    b(arguments);
}

function b(args){
    // arguments are lost?
}

a(1,2,3);
```

In function a, I can use the arguments keyword to access an array of arguments, in function b these are lost. Is there a way of passing arguments to another javascript function like I try to do?

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone Agreed.  Plus, note that `arguments` is not *actually* an array (but rather an [object that implements array-like semantics](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)) and therefore it is not entirely clear at first glance whether it can be used in the same way as an actual array can.

Comment: @Jules still **vote to reopen** after all these years. What's the badge for burninating other people's valuable work? A lot of those to go around.

Answer (score 586, accepted):

Use [`.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to have the same access to `arguments` in function `b`, like this:

```js
function a(){
    b.apply(null, arguments);
}
function b(){
    console.log(arguments); //arguments[0] = 1, etc
}
a(1,2,3);
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/UPMD3/).

Comment: What could you do to pass a portion of the arguments?

Comment: @Brett - You can copy it into an array then manipulate that before passing it along, for example: `var copy = [].slice.call(arguments); <remove what you want> myFunc.apply(this, copy);`

Comment: but using `apply` like this might screw up the scope of `b` (if it's some inner function of an object for example)

Comment: @vsync good point, but problem is easy to solve: pass the object as a first argument to apply.

Comment: does not make sense to use "args" and "arguments" together...

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation, tried that with another logger function on console.log.apply

Comment: But then the "this" might be changed to something other than b's original this.

Comment: julmot yes it does. 'arguments' is the name of a variable that is accessible within a function, regardless of what the actual arguments are named.

Comment: @vsync—functions are lexically scoped, so **how** they are called doesn't affect scope. You might be referring to the called function's *this*, but that is set by the call and has nothing to do with scope.

Comment: How about when writing `strict mode` JS?

Comment: i tested this before and its causes huge slow in performance spsly when u call this function inside a loop or timeout , so whoever who try to do this , be careful and look for other choices first .

Comment: The best answer for es5.

Answer (score 318):

### Spread operator

> The spread operator allows an expression to be expanded in places where multiple arguments (for function calls) or multiple elements (for array literals) are expected.

ECMAScript ES6 added a new operator that lets you do this in a more practical way: **...[Spread Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#Examples)**.

Example without using the `apply` method:

```js
function a(...args){
  b(...args);
  b(6, ...args, 8) // You can even add more elements
}
function b(){
  console.log(arguments)
}

a(1, 2, 3)
```

<kbd>Note</kbd> This snippet returns a syntax error if your browser still uses ES5.

<sup>Editor's note: Since the snippet uses `console.log()`, you must **open your browser's JS console to see the result** - there will be *no* in-page result.</sup>

It will display this result:

[image: Image of Spread operator arguments example]

In short, the spread operator can be used for different purposes if you're using arrays, so it can also be used for function arguments, you can see a similar example explained in the official docs: **[Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)**

Comment: This is a very nice operator and I'm really looking forward to use it. However, it won't happen yet. The only browser that already supports spread operator is FF at the moment. See the compatibility table for a complete, up to date data: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#spread_%28...%29_operator

Comment: Why shouldn't it be used? It's relatively easy to transpile with babel, you get all of the new features, and much more compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: This is better than the first solution because it works in function defined with the arrow operator.

Comment: You dont need `...args` in the `a` function. You can just make a function with no arguments and pass them on to `b` with `...arguments`

Comment: To anyone reading this answer: Contrary to @cronoklee's comment, explicitly specifying `...args` as `a`'s input can be important if you have nested functions.

Comment: In TypeScript, you may get an error: "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter."
To overcome this, use Parameters type as follows:
`
    function a(...args: Parameters<typeof b>) {
      b(...args);
    }
`
Or for another common complex example:
`
    async function a(...args: Parameters<typeof b>) {
      return await b(...args);
    }
`

Answer (score 84):

The explanation that none of the other answers supplies is that the original arguments *are* still available, but not in the original position in the `arguments` object.

The `arguments` object contains one element for each actual parameter provided to the function. When you call `a` you supply three arguments: the numbers `1`, `2`, and, `3`. So, `arguments` contains `[1, 2, 3]`.

```
function a(args){
    console.log(arguments) // [1, 2, 3]
    b(arguments);
}
```

When you call `b`, however, you pass exactly *one* argument: `a`'s `arguments` object. So `arguments` contains `[[1, 2, 3]]` (i.e. one element, which is `a`'s `arguments` object, which has properties containing the original arguments to `a`).

```
function b(args){
    // arguments are lost?
    console.log(arguments) // [[1, 2, 3]]
}

a(1,2,3);
```

As @Nick demonstrated, you can use `apply` to provide a set `arguments` object in the call.

The following achieves the same result:

```
function a(args){
    b(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]); // three arguments
}
```

But `apply` is the correct solution in the general case.

Comment: Should you always pass `this` to `apply`?

Comment: @Flimm—yes, since the arguments are the second argument, there has to be something for the first argument (it can be *null*).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only pass certain arguments, you can do so like this:

```
Foo.bar(TheClass, 'theMethod', 'arg1', 'arg2')
```

*Foo.js*

```
bar (obj, method, ...args) {
  obj[method](...args)
}
```

`obj` and `method` are used by the `bar()` method, while the rest of args are passed to the actual call.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this in Typescript, you may get an error.

`A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.`

To fix this you need to use `Parameters<Type>` to constructs a tuple type from the types used in the parameters of a function.

```
function a(...args: Parameters<typeof b>) { 
  b(...args); 
}
```

*I've created this answer from some comments on this page, which could be harder to find for anyone trying to find this.*

Answer (score 0):

This one works like a charm.

```
function a(){
    b(...arguments);
}

function b(){
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
       //you can use arguments[i] here.
    }
}

a(1,2,3);
```