# javascript: remove values from an array that are in a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using pure javascript, starting with an array, I would like to return and array by removing values that match any value in a second array.

I have solved this problem, but I believe with more code than is really necessary.

I am hoping for a more concise or elegant solution using only javascript.

```
function removeValues(arr){
    array = arguments[0];
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    len = arguments.length;
        filtered = array.filter(function(n){
            x = true;
            for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
                if (n == args[i]) { x = false; }
            }
            return x;
        });
    return filtered;
}

removeValues([1,2,3,1,2,3],2,3);
```

Should use a function that removes values from the first argument (an array) using values in one or more additional arguments.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/ but its not pure JS...

Comment: using only pure javascript

Comment: Why would anyone use jQuery for this?

Comment: Its not only this, but when u are making bigger app, framework is saving lot of time

Comment: agreed.  This is a JS algorithm problem, so not about saving time but practicing programming.  I will read the docs on grep though, thanks for that it was helpful.

Comment: anyone know why this question would have been down voted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're working with the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function is not necessary to use loops because you're already in a loop. After converting the arguments into an array with `[].slice.call(arguments)`,  you could use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) that is responsible for returning the position of a value in an array, if a value is not exists, this returns `-1`, so we will take all the results that are `-1`

Your code could be reduced as well:

```js
function removeValues(arr){
  return arr.filter(function(val){
    return [].slice.call(removeValues.arguments).slice(1).indexOf(val) === -1
  })
}

console.log(removeValues([1,2,3,1,2,3],2,3))
```

---

**ES6 Method:** Using [Rest parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31035825/1074519) and [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

[image]

```
var removeValues = (arr, ...values) => arr.filter(val => values.indexOf(val) === -1)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in the answer how this works?

Comment: If you mean to ES6 method, you could go to 2 typed links, is where is explained in detail about *Rest parameters* and *Arrow Functions*, the operation is the same

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead...

```
function removeValues(){
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
    return arguments[0].filter(function(value) {
        return args.indexOf(value) === -1;
    });
}

removeValues([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

It does the exact same thing, but tidies it slightly.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`, also take the first argument, to be exact should be: `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1)`. `args = ` in strict mode it will fail, it should be declared as local variable **var args =**

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
var array1 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ];
var array2 = [ 2, 3 ];

var result = array1.filter( function ( elem ) {
    return array2.indexOf( elem ) === -1;
});
```

See example: [Running code](http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/gn0hbqgv/)