# Arguments Object is turning my array into a list? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object, arguments

Does anyone know why using console.log inside of a function returns a list instead of the intended array?

```
function intToArray() {
  var array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
    array.push(arguments[i]);
  return array;
}

function printArray() {
  console.log(intToArray(arguments));
}

console.log(intToArray(1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,9));
// [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 8, 9]

printArray(1,2,3,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,9);
// [0:  {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 4, …}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing arguments forward to another javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914557/passing-arguments-forward-to-another-javascript-function)

Answer (score 1):

In first case you pass multiple arguments to `intToArray`:

```
intToArray(1, 2, ...)
```

In the second case you pass *a single* argument:

```
intToArray(arguments);
```

That's more equivalent to `intToArray([1,2,3])`.

In both cases an array is printed, but with different number of elements.

If you want to pass a long all arguments, see [Passing arguments forward to another javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3914557/218196).

Comment: The functions do not accept input parameters, so it is irrelevant what is passed to them.

Comment: @Jaco: You can pass as many or as few arguments to a function in JavaScript, no matter its formal parameters. Simplified example: `function foo() { alert(arguments[0]); }; foo('hello');`. `arguments` is a special variable in every function that is a collection of all arguments (who would have though!) passed. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments for more info.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Felix!