# Edit function but still call original function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to edit every function under the `UI` "class" to return their first argument but still run their native code.

Here is what I have tried:

```
for(var i in UI) {
    var cur = UI[i];
    UI[i] = function() {
        cur.call(this, arguments);
        return arguments[0];
    }
}
```

This returns my arguments but no longer runs the original function correctly as the UI element is not called.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code works as it is in the sense that it returns the first passed argument. But, clearly, `cur` is not defined. Where did you define it and what do you expect `this `to refer to?

Comment: isnt it better to use `function(...args)` instead of accessing it through arguments?

Comment: Basically I think we need more context. I. e.: please provide a "minimum" version of your UI class and some code showing us how you instanciate the class into an object.

Comment: Try using `.apply()` in place of `.call()`. -- [Passing arguments forward to another javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914557/passing-arguments-forward-to-another-javascript-function)

Comment: UI isn't created by me, it's in the API that I'm using which is why I need to edit it but still run it. I tried apply, didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) problem. There is only a single `cur` variable in your scope and it will have the value assigned to it in the last iteration of the loop.

Use `let` and pass the arguments along properly (via rest args and `apply`):

```
for(let i in UI) {
    let cur = UI[i];
    UI[i] = function(...args) {
        cur.apply(this, args);
        return args[0];
    }
}
```

If you are stuck with ES5:

```
for(var i in UI) {
  (function(cur) {
    UI[i] = function() {
        cur.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
        return arguments[0];
    }
  }(UI[i]));
}
```