# What's the difference between these two console.log overrides?

Tags: javascript

This overrides console.log without issue and it makes sense to me:

```
(function(c) {
  console.log = function() {
    c.apply(console, arguments);
  }
})(console.log);
```

This one does not work and I don't understand why:

```
(function(c) {
  console.log = function() {
    c(arguments);
  }
})(console.log);
```

I just get a list of properties when I call console.log.

What's the difference?

I need to build the array with arguments in the second one for it to work.

Comment: The modern solution would utilize [`rest parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) rather than the `arguments` object. This will also work with an arrow function. `(function(c) {console.log = (...args) => c(...args);})(console.log);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments forward to another javascript function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914557/passing-arguments-forward-to-another-javascript-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you modify your function like this:

```js
(function(c) {
  console.log = function() {
    // c(...arguments) also works
    c(...Object.values(arguments));
  }
})(console.log);

console.log('hello world')
```

This is because `arguments` is not an array, but an [array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

```js
function func(...args) {
    console.log(arguments);
}

func(1, 2, "hello", "world")
```

Comment: you don't need the `Object.values()` call. The `arguments` object may be spread directly, from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments#arguments_is_an_array-like_object): *'... it can be converted to a real Array, using one of `slice()`, `Array.from()`, or `spread syntax`.'*

Comment: @pilchard You're right, I have added that to my code, thanks. But I personally prefer adding `Object.values` to be more explicit since spreading objects as function arguments does not work in general.

Answer (score 2):

The second code example doesn't works as you expect it to because you are passing the `arguments` object as it is to the `console.log` function whereas in the first code example, due to the usage of `apply()`, the properties in the `arguments` object are passed as a *separate* argument. In other words, array or an array-like object is *spread* in to distinct arguments.

The `console.log` call in the first code example is similar to the following:

```
console.log(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...)
```

whereas in the second one, it is as:

```
console.log({ 0: arg1, 1: arg2, 2: arg3, ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(c) {
  console.log = function() {
    const a = Array.from(arguments);
    c(a.join(" "))
  }
})(console.log);
```

This works.

`arguments` is an object-like so we need to create the string ourselves.

Comment: Yes, much better. Thx.

Comment: Note that console.log is capable of a lot more than just sticking strings together, this will fail in many use cases.

Comment: joining them forces string coercion which isn't the behavior of  `console.log`. Skip the `join` and just spread the array `c(...a)` (or just spread the `arguments` object `c(...arguments)`)